# API for reading musical notes on iPhone

Tags: ios, image-processing, music-notation

In my application, I need to to open the camera and read the data as given below in attached image:

[image]

So by reading this the API should return me an audio file generated for the above image.

Do tell me if there is some other way to do this other than how I am trying.

Comment: Well, you haven't explained how you're trying other than using an API (which I think you hope already exists). I don't know if such an API exists right now, but it would be pretty cool if one were made...

Comment: Wow, now that's ambitious. I doubt that any such API exists, but maybe someone will surprise me. This is surely going to require multiple steps and multiple APIs. And that's some seriously old-looking engraving.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this: http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Audio/OpenOMR.shtml

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner here we require to scan the above image with camera and when the image is scanning it should play the audio file  of what is being read . SO this requires APi .

Comment: @mrugen: "API" is an architectural design. You don't *need* to build this as an API, but it would probably work a lot better if you did.

Comment: How do you plan to try doing this?

Comment: @Andrew: Cool!! How well does it work?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I actually don't know, never having used it.  I used to work at a company that had a music OCR as a feature in their (commercial) software, and I recall it working reasonably well.  That was several years ago.  To find the link I gave, I just searched Google.  It looks like there are now many music OCR software packages available.  BTW, from a technical standpoint, this problem is somewhat easier than text OCR.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenOMR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openomr/) is some GPL'd Optical Music Recognition code available on SourceForge, although there does not appear to be any iPhone/iOS port.  So you'd have to do a major port (including creating a JVM for iOS) to create an OCR API from this code.

There's some [history on the subject of Music OCR on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_OCR).